# iOS is automatically restarting the WiFi radio after an Interval

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, wifi, voip

I have created an iOS VOIP app. The reason behind creating a VOIP app was to make my application run in background. Well that is working fine. I am also connected to a host through TCP/IP.

The problem here is when the OS is restarting the wifi radio automatically at some interval, which results in a disconnection. Then I have to reconnect.

Can anyone help me to understand what exactly is causing this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things this could be. Firstly, are you running iOS 8? there have been some reported wifi issues with it. Just google iOS 8 wifi issues to see how many people are having similar issues.

Secondly, it's not too irregular for your wifi network to shuffle you around, so it could be either your wifi router itself, or the iPhone. I would probably try using manual ip allocation instead of DHCP on your router as a test.

Thirdly, your software obviously needs to be set up to handle dropouts etc - dropouts and package less etc are fairly common parts of any networking.